# Fastest way to search an array stored in a mySql column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find a better way to search arrays stored in my mySql database to decide if I want to return values from that row.  Currently I am parsing the entire array, and if it includes what I want, I go on to do whatever it is I want to do, and if it does not, I move on to the next row.  It's super slow.

I have array stored in a column, which we'll call category.  Ex: 1,zzz31zzz,31,4,5

I want to search that column, and if it contains "31", go on to manipulate my data.

So I access my db like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE arg=1 AND category != ''";
$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
  $vals = explode(',', $row['category']);
  foreach($vals as $val)
  {
    if($val == 31)
    {
      //do something
    }
    else
    {
    //dont
    }
  }
}
```

I feel like there is an obvious answer that I'm just not thinking about.  Can anyone suggest a better alternative?  I'm going to be processing thousands of arrays this way, and 3 takes nearly half a second as is.  I would be hesitant to use wildcards in my search, as it is possible that I could have data such as "1311" etc.. I pretty much need to search for a specific variable.

--
Thanks everyone for the immediate responses.  I will be able to test them here in a couple hours.  I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: do you need the rows which don't have the val==31 elsewhere?

Comment: why not filter it before fetching in mysql?

Comment: You have to normalize your database.

Comment: I do not need the rows that do not contain the specific variable.  Christian, filter how?

Comment: The obvious answer is to normalize your data.

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE arg=1 AND (category LIKE '%,31,%' OR category = 31 OR category LIKE '31,%' OR category LIKE '%,31'";
```

You won't match '1311', etc if I got what you want.

Otherwise, give a look at the `REGEXP SQL function`

Comment: @Jack Right, edited this. Anyway, I don't like the OR OR OR thing. I would rework the database scheme to store the categories another way I think. Not sure OP could do this though.

Comment: I will try this in the morning to see how it performs.  The only other way I can think to organize the db is to set columns such as 1,2,3,31, etc, and mark the rows as either 1 or 0 if they contain the variable I'm searching for.  It would take a lot longer to set up...  But would maybe offer a significant speed performance?

Comment: @user1129107 You create a new table `CATEGORIES (id, category, other_key)` where `other_key` is a foreign key to your first table. You can then find all the categories for the given key (and so id) by joining tables. There are many other solutions, you should learn a bit more about relational database maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Implying your delimiter is `,`

```
WHERE `category` REGEXP ',?[SEARCHED-VALUE],?';
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.  I'm going to check all this out in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

check this :->

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
  {
  $vals = explode(',', $row['category']);
  IF(in_array('31',$vals)
   {
    //do something
   }
  else
   {
    //dont
    } 
  }
```

**OR**

you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) with mysql queries

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I will check this out as soon as I get back to the computer.